# estou tentando fazer uma importação do react no navbar e não esta indo

Tags: javascript, java, react

import './App.css';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import navbar from './layout/navbar';
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0dY3.png)
function App() {
return (

```
 <navbar/>
</div>
```

);
}

export default App;
ERROR in ./src/App.js 6:0-37

Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'navbar.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\layout\Navbar.js'.

Answer (score -2):

eu estava com problema de sintaxe consegui resolver:D

import './App.css';
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import Navbar from './layout/Navbar';

function App() {
return (



);
}

export default App;